# Is it correct to say "She sometimes ties a knot in her T-shirt to show off her belly"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is it correct to say "**She sometimes ties a knot in her T-shirt to show off her belly**"?

Comment: What makes you think it might not be?

Comment: Correct perhaps, but ungallant and entirely lacking in chivalry. (Btw, do we **need** the pictures? Global warming etc...?)

Comment: Seconding @nick. Why do you ask this question? What specifically makes you think it might be incorrect? What research have you done to find an answer?

Comment: Other than the part where the shirts used generally aren't t-shirts, sure. (Much easier to tie something that has some kind of existing separation).

Comment: When I was a kid, we were taught that 'stomach' was polite, 'abdomen' was scholarly, and 'belly' was vulgar.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, do you get the impression that what you were taught is truthful?

Comment: @OmarL  yes I do. It was an accurate summary of usage at that time. These distinctions can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence.